# "weak" convergence in C (not L^1) ==> convergence in L^1

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Imagine I have $g_n, g \in\mathbb  L^1 (\mathbb R)$ that are non negative ($g_n,g\geq 0$) and I know that

$$\int_\mathbb R f(x) g_n(x) \mathrm dx \rightarrow \int_\mathbb R f(x) g(x)\mathrm  dx$$

for all $f \in C(\mathbb R)$ that are bounded. (Note: I don't assume for all $f\in \mathbb L^1$!)

Does this imply that $g_n \rightarrow g$ in $\mathbb L^1(\mathbb R)$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $R$? Is it the real line?

Answer (score 3):

Even if you did assume "for all $f\in L^1$", the answer would still be negative. Let $g_n(x)=(1+\sin  nx)\chi_{[0,2\pi]}$ and $g (x)= \chi_{[0,2\pi]}$. By the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, $\int fg_n\to \int fg$ for every $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$; in fact for every function that is   integrable on $[0,2\pi]$. Yet, $$\|g_n-g\|_{L^1} = \int_0^{2\pi}|\sin nx|\ge \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^2 nx  =\frac{\pi}{2}$$ does not tend to zero.